# C3P0 in Tomcat Cannot Connect to MySQL on localhost

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, c3p0

I trying to connect to a local MySQL database from a Spring app running in Tomcat, which I know is running but C3P0 is failing to acquire a connection.

**context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/cas">

    <Resource name="jdbc/dataSource"
              user="cas_app"
              password="cas_app"
              auth="Container"
              description="cas"
              initialPoolSize="6"
              acquireIncrement="6"
              minPoolSize="6"
              maxPoolSize="18"
              maxConnectionAge="25000"
              maxIdleTime="120"
              maxIdleTimeExcessConnections="300"
              idleConnectionTestPeriod="30"
              testConnectionOnCheckin="true"
              testConnectionOnCheckout="false"
              preferredTestQuery="SELECT 1"
              maxStatements="0"
              maxStatementsPerConnection="0"
              acquireRetryAttempts="5"
              acquireRetryDelay="2000"
              breakAfterAcquireFailure="true"
              driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
              jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/cas_ticket_registry?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
              type="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"

            />

</Context>
```

When I run Tomcat, I get the following errors

```
15-Jan-2016 06:28:30.314 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version.logVersion HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
15-Jan-2016 06:28:30.317 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.<clinit> HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
15-Jan-2016 06:28:30.319 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.buildBytecodeProvider HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
15-Jan-2016 06:28:30.592 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit> HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
06:28:40.748 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wj9ej5nr1f11ag6qu|76957520]-HelperThread-#2] ERROR com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - A RESOURCE POOL IS PERMANENTLY BROKEN! [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@bd387a8] (because a series of 5 acquisition attempts failed.)
06:28:40.748 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wj9ej5nr1f11ag6qu|76957520]-HelperThread-#0] ERROR com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - A RESOURCE POOL IS PERMANENTLY BROKEN! [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@6e3f8384] (because a series of 5 acquisition attempts failed.)
06:28:40.748 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wj9ej5nr1f11ag6qu|76957520]-HelperThread-#1] ERROR com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - A RESOURCE POOL IS PERMANENTLY BROKEN! [com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1916bfd5] (because a series of 5 acquisition attempts failed.)
06:28:40.753 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wj9ej5nr1f11ag6qu|76957520]-HelperThread-#0] ERROR com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@41ebd171 -- Unexpectedly broken!!!
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Unexpected Break Stack Trace!
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak(BasicResourcePool.java:974)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1000(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1927)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)

06:28:40.754 [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge0wj9ej5nr1f11ag6qu|76957520]-HelperThread-#1] ERROR com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@41ebd171 -- Unexpectedly broken!!!
com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Unexpected Break Stack Trace!
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.unexpectedBreak(BasicResourcePool.java:974)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$1000(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1927)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696)
```

I have also tried adding the port to the url so that it would be `jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cas_ticket_registry?useUnicode=yes&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"`, but that didn't make a difference.

However, when I can connect via the command line.

```
terskine@WOZNIAK:../~$ mysql -u cas_app -p cas_ticket_registry
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 7
Server version: 5.6.17 Homebrew

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select 1
    -> ;
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

I would really appreciate any help you can give.  Thanks.

Comment: hi. can you post the stack traces associated with the actual Connection acquisition failures? they'll be in your logs, prior to the Exception you are showing. (what you are showing is an effect of, unusually, setting breakAfterAcquireFailure to true. there's rarely any reason to do that. you might want to get rid if that setting.)